# Javascript Renaming object properties in Object.assign() function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that merges two arrays of object.

```
const obj = {
sales: [
    {date: '01 FEB 2020', value: 1200},
    {date: '05 FEB 2020', value: 3000},
    {date: '10 FEB 2020', value: 2000},
    {date: '15 FEB 2020', value: 2780},
    {date: '20 FEB 2020', value: 1890},
    {date: '25 FEB 2020', value: 2390},
    {date: '29 FEB 2020', value: 3490},
],
cost: [
    {date: '01 FEB 2020', value: 2000},
    {date: '05 FEB 2020', value: 1200},
    {date: '10 FEB 2020', value: 2800},
    {date: '15 FEB 2020', value: 2280},
    {date: '20 FEB 2020', value: 2000},
    {date: '25 FEB 2020', value: 3000},
    {date: '29 FEB 2020', value: 2490},
]}
```

as the value properties are same i want to change it to the parent name like: `sales, cost` etc

Below is the function i am trying

```
processDualChartsData( data1, data2, newProp1, newProp2, newProp3, limit ){
    let chartData = data1.map( (item, i) => Object.assign( {}, {newProp1: item.date, newProp2: item.value}, {newProp3: data2[i].value} ) )
    return chartData.slice(0, limit)
}
```

And using the function as

```
let barChartData = this.processDualChartsData( sales, cost, 'date', 'visitor', 'profit', 7 )
```

I expected the return from it like:

```
[{date: "01 Feb 2020", sales: 40, cost: 45}, .... ]
```

But i am getting

```
[{newProp1: "01 Feb 2020", newProp2: 40, newProp3: 45}, {.....}, .....]
```

Can i manage it anyhow?

Answer (score 3):

You need [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

You could omit `Object.assign` and use the new object directly.

```
let chartData = data1.map((item, i) => ({
        [newProp1]: item.date,
        [newProp2]: item.value,
        [newProp3]: data2[i].value
    }));
```